# Most time-efficient way of storing a 2D array in binary files

Tags: c, optimization, binaryfiles, multidimensional-array

I need suggestions about storing a 2D array in a binary file.
I need it to be extensive, to be able to add new rows and columns very fast.

So far i've come up with this approach: i allocate a fixed size of memory for each row and every time i add a new row i fill it with an overhead of memory (say 1000 bytes) so as i don't need to shift rows every time i add a new column. When the overhead memory is filled up, i add an overhead of another 1000 bytes and so on.

This method proved to be very inefficient because i have to jump over the rows when i add a new column.

Ideally, if i didn't need to add new rows or columns i would store each row contigously, but that's not possible for what i want.

Comment: Roughly how big are the matrices?

Comment: How many cells actually contain data (is the matrix 'sparse' ? What do  the cells contain, do they stem from a small domain, or are some values more probable than others?

Comment: Where do you need to add rows and columns? At the beginning, at the end, or in arbitrary positions?

Comment: @wildplasser : hundreds of thousands, it is not sparse, the elements can be any integer value

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is quite nice, in fact it is what many DBs (notabene oracle) use. To jump over the "where is my row" hurdle you could maintain an in-memory index of the rows, just a long[] storing file offset to the start of the row for each (or each 2nd, 4th, 8th, ...) row. This way you can jump to your row fast, then add your col as initially planned.

Comment: One more: If you write this index to disk and store every offset (a.o.t every 2^n th), you can make even further use of it: If a row gets too long, just move it to the end of the file, leaving its original location unused and ready for the next empty row. This way you don't have to move around the rows at all.

Comment: It sounds like a good idea, but i'm not sure what index you are talking about. You mean the file offset using a fpos_t pointer (C)?

Comment: Yep. This actually works - I used it when I had to create a tiny key-value store with wildly varying value lengths.

Comment: Ok i will try it out, but one thing i don't understand is how is fpos_t and fsetpos, fgetpos different compared to fseek?

Comment: You can use fseek, no problem: The point is you don't need to jump over one row after the other, allways reading the length, but you can go right to your needed row in one hop.

Comment: I don't get it, i already know the positions of all rows in my file, they are contigous blocks of memory stored in the file.

Comment: Yep. But they are of different length (or this is what I understood), some ore 1000 bytes, some are 2000 bytes etc. So to fseek() to the offset of row 10 you need to know the lengths of rows 0-9, either by hopping them or by having some sort of index. The latter is my proposition.

Comment: No, i actually know the size of each row.